# selecting menuitem using scanner class in java

Tags: java

I have 4 menu item.If user selects 1 it takes to option 1 which asks the user to enter three data, after the user enters all the three data inside first option it should display main menu from which user can select other options. But, once i enter to sub menu inside mainmenu option1 I couldnot choose other options.

This is my code

```
public class Test {

    static int menuItem,aprice;
    static double price1, price2, price3;
    static Scanner sc;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        displayMenu();

        sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        menuItem=sc.nextInt();


        if( menuItem==1) {
            System.out.println("House Details:");
            System.out.println("Enter price1: $");
            price1=sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter price2: $");
            price2=sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter price3: $");
            price3=sc.nextDouble();
            displayMenu();
            menuItem=sc.nextInt();

        }
        else if (menuItem==2) {
            System.out.println("Enter the price of furniture: $");
            aprice=sc.nextInt();
            displayMenu();
        }
        else if (menuItem==3) {
            displayMenu();
        }
        else if(menuItem==4){
            System.out.println("Result");
            System.out.println();
            displayMenu();
        }else {
            displayMenu();
        }

    }


    // This will display menu item
    public static void displayMenu() {
        System.out.println("Please select an option from the menu:\n1. Enter House Prices\n2. Enter furniture Price\n3. calculate result\n4. Exit System");

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to move your different actions to different methods, and use a switch statement to choose the method based on the number entered.

At the moment you prompt the user, act once, reprompt the user and then do not use the new prompt value, what you want to do is something like the pseudo-code below:

```
exit = false
while (!exit) {
  promptUser()
  int value = readOption()
  switch(value) {
     case 1:
       doThing1();
       break;
     case 2:
       doThing2();
       break;
     case 3:
       exit = true;
       break;
  }
}
```

This way you prompt the user and keep prompting them after each action until you are told to exit.

**Edit - Added modified original source**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

  static int menuItem, aprice;
  static double price1, price2, price3;

  public static void main(String... args) {

    final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean keepGoing = true;
    while (keepGoing) {
      System.out.println("Please select an option from the menu:");
      System.out.println("1. Enter House Prices");
      System.out.println("2. Enter furniture Price");
      System.out.println("3. calculate result");
      System.out.println("4. Exit System");
      menuItem = sc.nextInt();
      switch (menuItem) {
        case 1:
          System.out.println("House Details:");
          System.out.println("Enter price1: $");
          price1 = sc.nextDouble();
          System.out.println("Enter price2: $");
          price2 = sc.nextDouble();
          System.out.println("Enter price3: $");
          price3 = sc.nextDouble();
          break;
        case 2:
          System.out.println("Enter the price of furniture: $");
          aprice = sc.nextInt();
          break;
        case 3:
          System.out.println("Result");
          break;
        case 4:
          keepGoing = false;
          break;
        default:
          System.out.println("Unknown option");
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```